# How to make a single dimensional array with unknown number of elements?

Tags: pascal

I want to know, how to make a single dimensional array with unknown number of elements.

For example:

```
Name: array[1..x] of Integer;
```

where x is an integer the user enters later in the program.

Comment: Depends on your compiler. FPC, Delphi allows `name: array of Integer`

Comment: Ok, how do I assign the nubmer of elements now?

Comment: Use SetLength. I posted as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now. Didn't know about these dynamic arrays :), something new to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your array as dynamic, see [documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu15.html#x39-450003.3.1). You can use [`SetLength`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/setlength.html) to set its length at runtime, and `Length` to get the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want to make a dinamic link between variables, you need to use [Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Here is [an example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/pascal-and-delphi/threads/105142/help-with-linked-list-in-turbo-pascal) of how to make this.

Comment: This is not true. FreePascal and Delphi (the two most commonly used Pascal dialects now) both support dynamic arrays, and nothing in this question asked about linked lists or any other data structures (and nothing about a "dinamic link between variables" either. This is a simple integer array question.